# VS2012 changes my IIS Express configuration file detrimentally when opening solution

Tags: visual-studio-2012, iis-express

Given the following site, configured within applicationHost.config for IIS Express 7.5

```
<site name="MySite" id="1">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr2IntegratedAppPool">
      <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="path\to\the\site" />
      <virtualDirectory path="/VDir1" physicalPath="path\to\the\site" />
      <virtualDirectory path="/VDir2" physicalPath="path\to\the\site" />
      <virtualDirectory path="/VDir3" physicalPath="path\to\the\site" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
      <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:12345:localhost" />
    </bindings>
</site>
```

When opening this solution, from Source Control Explorer (TFS2010) using VS2012 - the act of opening the solution changes the XML structure so that each virtualDirectory node lives inside it's own application node (which VS2012 creates for me)

As this is a **legacy .NET 2.0** application, which *in it's wisdom*, references controls, files, etc across the virtual directories shown above - as soon as they are given their own application in the config file any calls from `/` to `/VDir1` or `/VDir1` to `/VDir3` (for example) fail with the error `"The virtual path X maps to another application, which is not allowed"`

I have no problem with that error and it's validity, but does anybody know how I can stop VS2012 from meddling with my config file.

Couple of other points

- applicationHost.config is source controlled (trivial)
- Solutions in question are set to "Use IIS Express" with the configuration settings such as hostname, port set inside the project properties.